# Cocoa Touch - Hypothetical Lag Comparisons

Tags: cocoa-touch, button, audio, ios, lag

Hey all, I'm developing a rhythm game for the iPhone at the moment, just wondered if anyone had any thoughts on the best pieces to use for reaction time.

I have all the coding worked out, and I've narrowed it down to about 2 ways:

1: Using instances of UIButton that bypass the UIControlEvent or whatever, in order to use touchesBegan and touchesEnded. I've found this to be a bit faster in the past.

2: Using UIViews with custom functions to change the state of the buttons. They would also use touches began.

The rhythm pads (eight of them) need to be able to play a sound with minimal lag, and provide some sort of feedback, i.e. changing the image of the button.

My question: Is it better to Use UIViews and make my own buttons, or actual UIButtons that have been subclassed to use touchesBegan etc?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Xcode - Xcode is just an IDE - you should tag it as `iphone`, `ios` and maybe `cocoa-touch` too.

Comment: Good point. I suppose it's sort of fallen into a habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that finds this while searching, using touchesBegan, ended, and moved is WAY faster. In terms of a rhythm game or application requiring fast input, this is the way to go.